# script for connecting to an amazon ec2 instance by public dns

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

I need to write a script that can start an aws instance by its public dns,
I can start the instance at the moment by using a filter with my instance name, but if I try to filter with the {tag:'Public DNS': my_publicdns}  I get an error. Is it even possible to filter by public dns?

```
my_publicdns = 'ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' 
myinstance = 'GA_brian_burroughs'

 def start_instance():

          try:
            inst = conn.get_all_instances(filters={'tag:Name': myinstance})[0].instances[0]
          except Exception:
            print('Error:', myinstance, 'not found!')

          if not inst.state == 'running':
            print('Starting', myinstance)
            inst.start()
          else:
            print(myinstance, 'already running or starting up!')
```

Comment: Does it have an Elastic IP address, or just an IP address assigned when the instance was launched?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this.

The EC2 instance does not have a public DNS address assigned until after it is started up.  IPv4 addresses are a scarce commodity, so AWS does not permanently assign them.  If you stop and start an instance, you may well get a different IPv4 address.  Since the AWS public DNS name is based on the IPv4 address, instances do not necessarily retain the same public DNS name when stopped and then started.

I would suggest instead assigning a meaningful tag to your instances that allow you to functionally accomplish what you are trying to accomplish by using the public DNS name.

Comment: thanks I got it done,I didn't need to start it by its dns just connect to it via its dns so i could automatically install an nginx web server, assignment spec is done now just have to do some extra stuff for a few extra marks, like monitoring cpu stats and creating a new instance if readings are above a certain threshold. Im new to python is there a monitoring class or some import I can use to do this?